# How to delete the Entry of a program in "Start Up programs" (msconfig)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-registry

There are some entries in **"*msconfig / StartUp programs /*"**  which I have actually disabled and I don't need them anymore in the start up list.

I would like to delete them off from the entries list so that the list looks simpler.

Is there a way I can delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902), which is basically a very much enhanced version of MSConfig, and then choose delete on any options you don't want.

(Please note that when you disable something in MSConfig, it simply "moves" it to a temporary registry key where it won't run and be out the way, for it to come up in another tool such as Autoruns, you may have to re-enable it first).

Alternatively, you look in the "Location" column of MSConfig and just manually navigate to the folder/location/registry key and delete it yourself.

Comment: wow :) [15 Characters]

Comment: this would possibly get rid of autorun virus :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply uninstall the application in Add/Remove programs.  That usually does it.

These apps are alos often in the C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup folder or C:\Documents and Settings\%userName%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup folder.  You can delete teh entry there if uninsatlling does not work.

Some applications will be uninstlled from the program folder.  So Start Programs Progam Name "uninstall program name"

Some require a regitry change which would require more info on teh exact application.

Comment: yup its a registry deal (so I have used a tag REGISTRY there) :)